# Should all my activities always extend ActionBarActivity while using AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I would like to apply Material Theme to my app and make it available also on devices not running Lolipop. My application targets: `android:minSdkVersion="14` and `android:targetSdkVersion="21"`. I've made a simple test application and changed themes in styles.xml to:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

My test app looks OK. The question is: should all my activities extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity` in the application which uses AppCompat? If so, why?

Comment: The ActionBar was introduced in API Level **11**. So, **you don't need the AppCompat** at all!

Comment: I know this, but I want to apply Material Theme to all platforms on which my application will be running and AppCompat is the way to achieve this.

Comment: Ah, the Material theme! I see.

Comment: If you want apply Material theme for previous Android platforms, AppCompat is required. Otherwise you will get Material theme only on Lollipop devices when you define AppTheme (not Theme.AppCompat but Theme.Material..) in values-v21 directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually depends of what you are building. In most cases the answer is **yes, all should extend `ActionBarActivity`**

If every activity extends `ActionBarActivity` you can use `android:theme="AppTheme"` under `application` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ... />
```

---

On the other hand, if for some reason you cannot always extend `ActionBarActivity`, then
theme `"AppTheme"` should paired with `ActionBarActivity` and `Activity` should have the basic android theme eg. `android:Theme.Holo.Light` at each `activity` tag of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity android:name=".ActionBarActivityChildren" 
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ... /> 

<activity android:name=".ActivityChildren"
          android:theme="android:Theme.Holo.Light" ... />
```

So, it is possible to not always extend `ActionBarActivity` but you actually never do it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to extend ActionBarActivity. In Android Studio you declare your .jars etc in your /app/build.gradle file like this :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0' 
}
```

make sure your version (here 21.0.0) is not higher than your buildToolsVersion(Current is 21.0.2) which are downloaded from the SDK.

In Eclipse you grab your libraries through the project.properties file like this :

```
target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7_8
```

Hope that helps!